# Split Eval in DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, eval

Hello I have an Eval value (one;two;three) which I want to split and display it in DropDownList.

> DataSource='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DataNames")).Split(';')[] %>'

This line doesn't work and gives me error: The server tag is not well formed.

Also if I leave DataSource like this:

> DataSource='<%# Eval("DataNames") %>'

I get every single character in a new line.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Just remove `[]` at the end. That is incorrect syntax. If you wanted to make sure data source is an array - you are safe here since `Split` already returns an array

Comment: Still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

1. `[]` is an incorrect syntax
2. Single quotes are already used aroung the attribute value so you need to escape them inside the `Split` call.

Result should be something like that:

```
DataSource='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DataNames")).Split(\';\') %>'
```

**Update.** So apparently quotation is still wrong. You can try also using string instead of char in `Split` call (remember it has second parameter):

```
DataSource='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DataNames")).Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) %>'
```

Or let go the outer quotes completely:

```
DataSource=<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("DataNames")).Split(';') %>
```

Comment: i haven't thought about that. but still Split part gives me error

Comment: Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. If I remove Split part - everythings ok.

Comment: @CapeNotrio, please see update. Too bad I do not have a VS at the moment to try different options